# Oracle Content Server page title HCSF Pages?

Tags: oracle

How do i modify the meta tags, title, desc... in Oracle UCM?  Do i have to ask admin for access to HCSF Pages?

I cant find it in content server anywhere.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to metadata , adding them , editing them or their labels you would need to have access to the configuration manager admin applet. This access needs to be given by the administrator .